# Passing a property's type extracted with reflection as T

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, types, delegates

Suppose I have a Person class that looks like this:

```
Person
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Age {get; set;}
}
```

And I have a method that takes a type T and a string as parameters

```
someMethod<T>(Action<T> someAction, string propertyName)
```

Is there a way to do something like this for each of a Person instance's property

```
Person p = new Person(){};

foreach(var propInfo in p.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    someMethod<propInfo.PropertyType>(someAction, propInfo.Name)
}
```

Comment: Your question is (definitely) a duplicate of [How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method)

Comment: This looks like C# except for the missing `class` keyword on your definition of `Person`, is it?